# How to estimate requests per second for an GPS tracking app

Tags: parse-platform, gps, geolocation, mbaas

I am going to develop an Android application that enables tracking (and monitoring on map interface) of multiple users by a specific user. For this reason, I want to study on a mBaaS, Parse. However I cannot figure out how much requests per second performed by such an app considering the count of users. To exemplify, if I choose free option for the monthly cost, the limit will be 30 requests per second. I have some doubts about whether this number is sufficient for this app.

In other words, there will be periodic API requests (let's say every 30 seconds) for all users that are tracking. I think it is highly possible to exceed the limit of 30 requests per second with a very few active users. Even if 5 different users track 10 different users at the same time, the probability of catching 30 requests per second is very high.

Considering all these, what kind of strategy you advise? How can I manage periodic geolocation requests in this system? Is Parse the right choice? If not, any better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

The approach used in [Traccar GPS tracking system](https://www.traccar.org/) is to return all user's objects in one request. So, say if you want one user to track 100 other users, you still need only one request to get all 100 locations.

You can optimize it further by not sending location if it hasn't changed. So, if only 10 users from 100 changed their location since last request, you can return only 10 location items in response.

Comment: I wanted to take a look but when I try to run the jar file of your Windows server, it said: "WARN no appenders could be found for logger". I think there is a problem with the source code, if not it means instructions are not clear and so please explain me how to run.

Comment: You need to specify a path to the config file as a command line argument. Example of a config file can be found in the root folder of the repository - debug.xml (you have to change paths inside).